# How to change color of current week in MaterialCalendarView?

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, calendarview

I want to change the colour of the WeekDay text for the current week. I am able to change the colour for the current day using a decorator. Is it possible to do this while using this library?

Link to the library: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**if you using**

```
'com.github.shuwnyuantee:Material-Calendar-View:1.3'
```

week layout in **calender_view.xml**

**to manage your condition , you will have to change inside CalenderView.java file**

because the ID of the week layout is being found here.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, i am using this lib: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: i try if found ,i will definitely tell you